# How do I implement structured data for questions and answers to get "Best Answer" rich snippets in Google?

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, structured-data

I want to get rich snippets in Google for Q&A like StackOverflow.  How do I do this? What structured data do I need?

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Google Search Results displaying question and answer rich snippets]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to apply the properties identified in both the [Question scheme](http://schema.org/Question) and [Answer scheme](http://schema.org/Answer) as defined on Schema.org.

In particular and at minimum, use the following attributes/properties:

1. `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question"` on the DOM element wrapping entire set of question & answer content
2. `itemprop="name"` (typically on an H1) wrapping the individual question
3. `itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer"` on the DOM element wrapping the accepted answer
4. `itemprop="suggestedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer"` on the DOM element wrapping other answers

You may also (optionally) want to consider attributing questions and answers to individual people/users, using the [Person scheme](http://schema.org/Person).

---

Below are screenshots of one of the examples from schema.org for quick reference.

**Microdata**
[image: Microdata approach]

**RDFa**
[image: RDFa approach]

**JSON-LD**
[image: JSON-LD approach]